# Rails fields_for from collection with checkboxes & additional attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested-attributes, fields-for

Reference: [Rails has_many through form with additional attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704845/rails-has-many-through-form-with-additional-attributes)

But it is not solution for me... I want to accept only checked elements, without dependency if other attributes are filled.

E.g.: I want to create my menu. There is each food with checkbox and you are able to edit the price in text field (but you don't have to). I want accept all checked foods & save their new price if filled, or old price if not.